# Problems with using macro in c++

Tags: visual-c++

I am using MS-Windows XP SP3 and Visual C++ compiler. Now when I define one macro as-

```
#define APPVERSION(n) ((int32)0 + n)
```

and used it as -

```
if(APPVERSION(2)>= APPVERSION(1)) it is giving me an error as
```

fatal error C1012: unmatched parenthesis : missing ')'

but when I use that macro as -

```
#define APPVERSION(n) (0L + n)
```

It works without any error.

What is exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to answer without you providing the **complete** error message, but I'm guessing it includes something like this as the *first* line in the error message:

```
error C2065: 'int32' : undeclared identifier
```

You have to make sure that the type-alias `int32` exists, either by including the correct header where it's defined or define it yourself. And by "define" I mean there should be either a preprocessor `#define` directive or a `typedef`.

Comment: No, actually the error message is- 

fatal error C1012: unmatched parenthesis : missing ')'

Comment: @vDeepak Then please edit your question to include the _complete_ error message, copy-paste it. When you post questions about error messages, you should always include the _complete_ and _unedited_ message(s) in the question. It really helps us understand what may be wrong.